# Find the supremum of $\{\sqrt{(u+av)^2+v^2}\mid \sqrt{u^2+v^2}=1 \}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $u,v,a\in\mathbb{R}$. Find the supremum/maximum of $\{\sqrt{(u+av)^2+v^2}\mid \sqrt{u^2+v^2}=1 \}$

So if $ \sqrt{u^2+v^2}=1$ then $u^2=1-v^2$ and $u=\sqrt{1-v^2}$

So $\sqrt{(u+av)^2+v^2} = \sqrt{u^2+2avu + 4v^2+v^2} = \sqrt{1-v^2+2av\sqrt{1-v^2} + 4v^2+v^2} = \sqrt{1+2av\sqrt{1-v^2} + 4v^2}$

How do I find the maximum now? I think it should be in terms of $a$.

Comment: What's a bound on the value for $v$?

Comment: There isn't any bound

Comment: @clocktower The condition $\sqrt{u^2 + v^2} = 1$ gives the bound.

Answer (score 0):

$u=\cos t, v=\sin t,$ then we have the function of 1 variable  $(u+av)^2+v^2=\ldots.$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Notice here the condition on your set limits $u$ and $v$ to be the set of points ($u = x, v = y$ for example) on the unit circle centered at the origin. You can use the transformation $u = \sin(\theta), v = \cos(\theta)$ and take it from there with the derivative tests on a suitable interval for $\theta$.

Your assumption here about $a$ is also important so keep in mind when it's positive, negative, zero.